# Permission denied when opening folder on Raspberry Pi Network Attached Storage (NAS) with VS Code Command Line Interface (CLI)

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, permission-denied, samba, nas

I installed Raspbian Lite and Samba on my Raspberry Pi 4b.
Below is my smb.conf file.

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = no

[home]
   path = /mnt/raid1
   writeable = yes
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   public = no
   read only = no
   browseable = yes
```

I access the server from a Windows 10 and a Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) client. Everything works fine on the Windows client. The first time I try to open a folder that is on the Raspberry Pi via the VS Code Command Line Interface(CLI) `code` after logging into the Linux client, it works. However, every additional time I try to open a folder that is located on the NAS via `code`, no matter which flag I use, I get the following error:

```
cannot stat path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

When I use vim to open a folder on my NAS, everything works fine. In addition, the workspace for the Eclipse IDE is stored on the Raspberry Pi, and Eclipse has no problem with that. I can change and save files on the NAS except with the CLI `code`.

I only get this error from the VS Code Command Line Interface when working with folders stored on the NAS. When I work on my local hard drive or an external hard drive, there are no errors. Even if I open VS Code via the desktop icon and open a folder that is stored on the NAS in the GUI, no error occurs here either.

Below are the rights and owner of the mount point from my NAS on my Linux client

```
rwxr-xr-x niko   niko (niko is the user account on my Linux client)
```

Here are the rights and owners of the folders on the mount point of my hard drive on the Raspberry Pi, which can be accessed over the network using SMB protocol

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 pi   pi
    ├── some folder
    ├── drwx------ 2 pi   pi
    ├── some folder
    ├── drwx------ 4 pi   pi
    │   ├── drwxrwxrwx 2 pi   pi
    │   └── drwxrwxrwx 3 pi   pi
    │       └── drwxrwxrwx 20 pi   pi
    │           ├── drwxrwxrwx 41 pi   pi
    │           └── -rwxrw-rw-  1 pi   pi
    └── some folder
```

- Instead of the folder and file names, I added the rights (user, group, other) and the name of the user and group which own the folders and files on the Raspberry Pi. As you can see, when I am logged in with the user pi, every file, folder, and subfolder in the mount point directory belongs to the user pi and the group pi.

Here is the line from `/etc/fstab` I use to automount the Samba server

```
//192.168.178.96/home /media/samba cifs credentials=/Path/To/My/Credentials,users,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Here are the extensions I installed for VS Code in case the error could have something to do with an extension:

- AVR Support
- Better Comments
- C/C++
- Checkstyle for Java
- Cloudfoundry Manifest YML Support
- Code Runner
- Concurse CI Pipeline Editor
- Debugger for Java
- Docker
- Eclipse New Java Project
- Java Extension Pack
- Java Test Runner
- Jetty for Java
- Jupyter
- Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat
- Linux Themes for VS Code
- Material Icon Theme
- Maven for Java
- PlatformIO IDE
- Project Manager for Java
- Pylance
- Python
- Remote - Containers
- Spring Boot Dashboard
- Spring Boot Extension Pack
- Spring Boot Tools
- Spring Initializr Java Support
- Tomcat for Java
- Visual Studio IntelliCode
- x86 and x86_64 Assembly
- XML
- ESLint

I also have a permission problem when trying to install anaconda3 on the NAS. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65519287/permission-denied-when-installing-anaconda3-on-raspberry-pi-network-attached-sto) is the link to my other question, I guess these two are related.

Thanks in advance for your help and feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by reinstalling VS Code.